# DB for only do SELECT querys

Tags: android, sqlite

I really need to create a small DB for doing **only** SELECT querys in my app. Because of that I would like to know:

1. Does android provide something for design and fill a DB? I mean no programming. Something like phpmyadmin so I could fill it and make a relation between 2 tables before running the app in an emulator or a phone.
2. If I create a DB, will it be visible from some file in the user mobile phone? Because I read in android manual that it was invisible but in some places I read that it's saved in the mobile... I would prefer that this DB would be like a resource like it can be a layer or a string.
3. If I really need to create a DB each time the app is displayed for present the same information always, could I just "upload a sample" of that database in one line of code or so?

I need this for display a big list of items (maybe 2000 items) in different languages. I could do that just creating an array string resource but I need to order the list in a different way  depending on the location of the user. At the end I need to retrieve an "ID" of the items selected but because it's impossible to do a 2D array string as a resource then I can't assign a number to the items so I can only know their positions in the list. The problem is that if I alter the items I will have a mismatch of positions numbers as ID.

This array is for an autofill text. I know I can put a comma after each item with the number and before adding this array to the autofill do a split and select the first column for the autofill and the second for compare position to real ID but I thought it would have a better performance to have all in a DB. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1. Does android provide something for design and fill a DB? I mean no
    programming. Something like phpmyadmin so I could fill it and make a
    relation between 2 tables before running the app in an emulator or a
    phone.
```

You can use [Sqlite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to create a database

```
 2. If I create a DB, will it be visible from some file in the user  
     mobile phone? Because I read in android manual that it was invisible
    but in some places I read that it's saved in the mobile... I would
    prefer that this DB would be like a resource like it can be a layer
    or a string.
```

It depends on where you create. Usually if you open a database it will be created in /data/data/[yourpackagename]/databases . This folder is incaccessible in normal cases,  but if you have a rooted phone you can access this folder. Also while creating you could change the path to sdcard which is accessible everytime

```
  3. If I really need to create a DB each time the app is 
     displayed for present the same information always, could I just "upload a
    sample" of that database in one line of code or so?
```

You could store the db in assets folder of your app and open it.

Edit:

If it is just a 2D array i think its better to save as a csv and extract. You could put it in assets or raw folder.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that software and to look some web to store it in asset folder. About "data/data/[yourpackagename]/databases" it sounds to me like it is created insider apk??? So a root user can look inside apk? Or it's just a temp folder for each apk? I think it should be a method to have a db information 100% invisible at least the programmer doesn't matter to show it. Users who could be interested in see the DB data will have rooted his phones. What a pity. EDIT: Have you some code for so? some page?

Comment: No the storage is not inside apk, its at /data/data/ partion, apk will be present in /data/app . /data/data/[packagename] is a permanent folder for each apk, this is where all preferences are stored.